# Problems using Brother DCP-145C USB Scanner

Tags: peripherals, driver

I'm trying to use my old Brother DCP-145C Multifunction USB-Printer as a network printer/scanner with the RPi. I roughly followed [this guide](http://dev.shyd.de/2011/03/debian-printserver-scanserver-hplip-cups-sane/) so far:

Setting up the printing functionality via CUPS worked out pretty fine, however I've gotten stuck in configuring the estabishing the scanning functionality. After installing / updating inetutils-inetd and sane-utils, enabling SANE and configuring inetd I downloaded and installed the brscan3-driver and the "scan-key-tool" from the [brother homepage](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_scn.html). As Brother only provides these in 32bit and 64bit versions I chose the 32bit versions and installed both via dpkg and "--force all", as the instructions from brother state.
This worked out fine for the printer drivers, so I hoped it would as well for the scanner.

After restarting inetd and sane I ran "sane-find-scanner" :

```
  $ sane-find-scanner

  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.
  # Also you need support for SCSI Generic (sg) in your operating system.
  # If using Linux, try "modprobe sg".

 found USB scanner (vendor=0x04f9, product=0x0206) at libusb:001:004
 found USB scanner (vendor=0x0424, product=0xec00) at libusb:001:003
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.

  # You may want to run this program as root to find all devices. Once you
  # found the scanner devices, be sure to adjust access permissions as
  # necessary.
```

However when trying "scanimage -L" :

```
$ scanimage -L

No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
```

And when I'm trying to execute the brother scan-key-tool, I get the following error:

```
$ brscan-skey
$ /opt/brother/scanner/brscan-skey/brscan-skey-0.2.4-0: 1: /opt/brother/scanner/brscan-skey/brscan-skey-0.2.4-0: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Could this be caused by the architecture mismatch between the 32bit-Driver and Scan-Key-Tool and the arm-system? If so, could there be any solution (as brother only provides 32bit and 64bit-versions) for the problem? I've been searching for hours now for a solution and couldn't find any helpful information.

Comment: 32bit, 64bit and ARM are all different architectures.

Answer (score 1):

When vendors provide binary Linux drivers, they're almost always for x86. Brother is no exception; those archives are for i386/x86_64, not armhf. They will not run on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: So there is no way to use the scanner with the Raspberry Pi? I wonder why the drivers work for the printer.

Comment: The printer might already be supported through GhostScript/CUPS, so it may not be using a binary driver.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been few years and OP might no longer needs this, but I was exploring the topic and almost always ended up here. I have figured it out how to run Brother Scanner on RPi using QEMU.

I have used mainstream Debian 10 (not Raspberry Pi OS). I had to use mainstream Debian as packages in Raspberry Pi OS are suffixed with some tag and so I was unable to install i386 packages along arm ones on RPi OS.

First of all I have installed `apt install qemu binfmt-support qemu-user-static`.

Next I have added foreign architecture, i386, to my Debian installation:

`dpkg --add-architecture i386` and run `apt update`.

I have installed i386 version of Sane

`apt install sane-utils:i386`

and finally installed Brother i386 drivers with dpkg

`dpkg -i brscan4-0.4.10-1.i386.deb`.

This way I have i386 sane and brother drivers run through qemu and scanning works on my RPi2B+.

I suggest to remove all unused backends on `/etc/sane.d/dll.conf` to speedup finding scanner a little bit.

Comment: Well, I no longer have the printer nor the raspberry pi, but it was pretty interesting to see what has been bothering me 9 years ago - Thanks for the reply!